# How to recalculate a 3d normal when the model is scaled?

Tags: c#, vector, 3d, quaternions

I have a 3d model and I want to recalculate the normal when the model is scaled (non uniformly).
For example, I have a 3d model and when i scale non uniformly, the normal should be affected

1) Figure 1, the model is not scaled.
2) Figure 2, the model is scaled and the normal is affected.
(N is the normal).

[image: normals]

Comment: (Did not downvote) Simply scale the normal by the same proportions and normalize.

Comment: Are you specifically working in C#? Using Unity3D? Do you need a formula or a code representation?  What have you tried in code?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `quaternions` has to do with an issue of scaling.

Comment: I am using c# so I am free to use whatever expression that I want too.  And quaternion is usually used for doing a 3d conversion.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Let's say the next normal(0.0000,0.9008,-0.4343) (x,y,z), how i can obtain the proportion?.. If I scale for 200%,200%,200%, then the normal shouldn't be affected.However, if  I scale by 100%,1000%,100%, then it's affected.

Comment: Did you read my comment? Scale + *normalize*. If you are to scale something then you must already have the proportions.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes, I was working on it. Thanks.

Comment: Normals should NOT be updated during scaling of model. Normal represents Direction only and have magnitude 1.0 .

Comment: Normals should be updated if the scale is not proportional. You can see the image. 1) is 45º while 2) (that was scaled in the Y-axis) is 35º

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public Vector ModifyNormal(Vector v)
    {
        var re = new Vector();
        re.x = v.x  * xScale; 
        re.y = v.y  * yScale; 
        re.z = v.z * zScale;
        double magnitude =Math.Sqrt(re.x * re.x + re.y * re.y + re.z * re.z);
        // normalizing
        re.x = re.x / magnitude;
        re.y = re.y / magnitude;
        re.z = re.z / magnitude;
        return re;
    }
```

Comment: This solution works and it was downvoted. C'MON!.  It's the reason why StackOverflow is going down: nerds!.

Comment: Sorry, this is my miss. I didn't noted that scaling in NONuniform.  I must wait some time, before i be able to revert it.